# binding data in different order produces the same histogram

Tags: r

I have this data:

```
hours <- 1:5
frequency <- c(41, 72, 48, 20, 21)
```

I am binding them:

```
result <- cbind(hours, frequency)


result
     hours frequency
[1,]     1        41
[2,]     2        72
[3,]     3        48
[4,]     4        20
[5,]     5        21
```

and I am plotting the histogram:

```
hist(result)
```

which gives me [image: this image]

I would expect to have at x axis the hours.

So, I am trying to create :

```
result <- cbind(frequency, hours)
```

which gives:

```
result
     frequency hours
[1,]        41     1
[2,]        72     2
[3,]        48     3
[4,]        20     4
[5,]        21     5
```

but trying to make the histogram it shows me again the same as previous.
I would expect to change axes.

Comment: Your just plotting a histogram of all the individual values in that table. That's why the first bin is so high (it contains hours 1 to 5).

Comment: You want a barplot and not a histogram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hist` accepts the raw data, before they  summarized in a frequency table. The following code solves this, by recreating the data:

```
hours <- 1:5
frequency <- c(41, 72, 48, 20, 21)
result <- cbind(hours, frequency)

# rebuild the data and plot
result_obs <- rep(hours, frequency)
hist(result_obs)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use `barplot`.

```
hours <- 1:5
frequency <- c(41, 72, 48, 20, 21)
df <- cbind(hours, frequency)
barplot(df[,2], names.arg = df[,1])
```

[image]

Comment: Or simply `barplot(frequency, names.arg = hours)`.

Comment: Thanks!I prefer though the solution with the hist.(upvoted)